# query a set of elements, but in a particular order

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of `<div>` elements, each of which has a `name`. I would like to query the `<div>` elements using jQuery, but I want them to come by alphabetical order with respect to `name`. The usual code

```
$("div").doStuff()
```

doesn't return the elements in any special order.

Comment: Actually, it returns elements in the order they appear in the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$($("div").get().sort(function(a,b){
    if($(a).attr("name") === $(b).attr("name"))
        return 0;
    return $(a).attr("name") < $(b).attr("name") ? -1 : 1;
})).each(function(){ $(this).doStuff(); });
```

Comment: Actually, doesn't work. The second `$()` call destroys the ordering done previously.

Comment: @Randomblue Hmm interesting to know. I changed it so that it keeps it as an array now.

Comment: @Randomblue It actually worked. I just had an error and was comparing a and b directly instead of their name attributes. It works now :) http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/PrfZy/

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any way to do this other than getting the list of elements into a normal JS array, sorting that array by name, putting them back into a jQuery object then calling your final operation on them in that sorted order.

```
function compareNameAlpha(a, b) {
   var n1 = a.getAttribute("name");
   var n2 = b.getAttribute("name");

   if (n1 < n2) return(-1);
   if (n1 == n2) return(0);
   return(1);
}

var elArray = $("div").toArray().sort(compareNameAlpha);
$(elArray).doStuff();
```

or done all in one line:

```
$($("div").toArray().sort(compareNameAlpha)).doStuff();
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qeLfX/

---

**Edit:** There appears to be an even simpler way to do this as jQuery supports `.sort()` directly (though it is marked in the jQuery source as for internal use only).  You can do this:

```
$("div").sort(compareNameAlpha).each(doStuff);
```

And see that version here http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hJhhf/

Comment: Yeah, it sucks, but there's no other way to do it.  You can't "query" DOM elements.  You can only select them and work with their content and attributes.  I'm sure you can find a jQuery plugin that will help you with this too.

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually, doesn't work. The `$()` in `$(elArray)` destroys the ordering done previously.

Comment: @Randomblue - Actually, the issue appears to be that the sort function didn't work so the sort order was never correct.  I fixed the sort and now it seems to work.  You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qeLfX/.

Comment: I did a little fishing through the jQuery source and it actually supports the sort() method directly on the internal array of IDs so I've added that version too.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is untested, but I think you could do something along the lines of the following:

```
$($("div").get().sort(sortFn)).each(doStuff);
```

where `sortFn` is a proper argument to `Array.sort` that sorts elements by name attributes.

Comment: Actually, doesn't work. The second `$()` call destroys the ordering done previously.

Comment: @Randomblue, I'm fairly sure it does work; `.each` preserves ordering.  Also, PaulPRO's jsfiddle does exactly this and it works correctly.

Comment: In fact, the second `$()` query could not destroy the ordering done previously, since you query only a single element (one array).  You can't destroy ordering only one element.